# Use RxJava Flowable - how to split the emission according to the type of the event

Tags: java, firebase, rx-java

Let's say we use Firebase ChildEventListener which can be taken as multiple sources of data (its functions) and I'm wrapping it with Flowable or Observable. I want that in each source, the emitter will emit the data to a different pipeline because in each case the data can be changed I want to handle it in different ways - that is, splitting the emission into several different streams according to the type of the event.

How can this be done in Java?

```
  public void newUsers() {
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("Users");
    Flowable.create(emitter -> {
        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                User userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                emitter.onNext(userData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
             User userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                emitter.onNext(userData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             User userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                emitter.onNext(userData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                emitter.onNext(userData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
             User userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                emitter.onNext(userData);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't you use different emitters to have multiple streams?

Comment: I would be love to do that, but I don't know if it is possible to separate the functions of ChildEventListener so the Flowable wraps all the functions together. Do you have any idea how could it be done? @Shark

Comment: yes, of course. lemme refactor this thing... dunno if it's the right approach, but that's what i'd try first instead of a single flowable.

Comment: posted something, give it some thought @nirkov

Answer (score 1):

So, to have multiple streams, we can't have a single `Flowable`. I dunno whether a Flowable is actually a requirement, so i'll just outline my idea, you feel free to correct it and adapt to your needs.

```
   BehaviourSubject childAddedStream;
   BehaviourSubject childChangedStream;
   BehaviourSubject childRemovedStream;
   BehaviourSubject childMovedStream;
   BehaviourSubject cancelledStream;

  public void newUsers() {
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("Users");
    
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                User userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                childAddedStream.onNext(userData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
             User userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
             childChangedStream.onNext(userData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             User userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
             childRemovedStream.onNext(userData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            childMovedStream.onNext(userData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
             User userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
             cancelledStream.onNext(userData);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

something like this would be my starting point.

The idea is for this class to initialize different Subjects for each callback, register the callback to the FirebaseDatabase when it's created, and route the individual callbacks to different streams (subjects, feel free to use a more relevant Subject that BehaviourSubject if you want) - then whoever needs to listen just listens for the relevant stream instead of the single Flowable which simply acts like a bridge between the callback and reactive world.

Comment: Alternatively, you can go with something similar to your idea - but you need 5 flowables, and have each one of them listen to (and emit) only one callback.

Comment: Or, you go with emitting a `Pair<UserData, EventType>` and use only one flowable - and by filtering on EventType enum - e.g. `REMOVED, CHANGED, MOVED, ADDED`, you get your multiple streams. I still think you need a Subject in that case, but a single subject could serve all five of these streams via filtering.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. What if I need the Flowable backpressure strategy ability? For example in the case of ```onChildAdded``` there are some computations that can take a while (download images/saving images etc) and I am afraid it will cause a missing values and crashes

Comment: Maybe there is a way that I can combine your great idea about using Enum with several Flowable streams?

Comment: You don't need multiple flowables if one emits a pair; filtering one stream based on the `EventType` will make multiple streams that all share same backing data. You either use a single Subject/Flowable emitting a pair (and get multiple streams by filtering) or you have one Subject/Flowable per callback. It's that simple.

Comment: If you go with the EventType enum thing (and emit a pair) - your thing is already fine, just needs the appropriate enum to go with the UserData, so the consumer can differentiate by event, and filter on the appropriate EventType.

Comment: cc @nirkov (pinging because you wont see coments made on my post)